# How to write an Webservice API Wrapper the drupal 7 way

Tags: 7

I have been trying to find a standardized way of writing a Webservice API Wrapper the drupal 7 way but I was not able to find any documentation on this.
How does one write an Webservice API wrapper for Drupal 7? An example will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post sample code of what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution is to use the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services), which provides hooks for you to define your own endpoints.

There's also [Restful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) which has similar functionality but is geared more towards entity API integration.

If you literally want to write your own API from scratch then just use your best judgement - there aren't any Drupal-specific standards for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [services views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views), It can be used with views Module.

> Views support for the Services module version 3.x and later.
>
> It has currently two features:
>   - Create view based resource creating Services display in a view
>   - Execute any view of the system via views resource call
>
> Demo video http://youtu.be/DZEhJKMeR5w